# How is the instanton Floer homology of Seifert fibrations related to that of a trivial fibration

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology

My question centers around the relationship of the Chern-Simons theories of a Seifert fibration and the trivial product space $\Sigma_g \times S^1$, and its implication for instanton Floer homology. Here, $\Sigma_g$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$.

Let $M_{g,p}$ be the Seifert manifold that is presented as a degree $−p$, $U(1)$
bundle over a Riemann surface  of genus $g$.
In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2885) paper by Thompson, it is explained that Chern-Simons theory for $M_{g,p}$ and $\Sigma_g \times S^1$ are closely related. This is essentially due to the fact that every 3-manifold has a contact structure, and for $M_{g,p}$ the natural contact structure, $\kappa$, is the $U(1)$ connection on the $U(1)$ bundle used in its definition. As explained above equation 2.2 of the paper by Thompson, this corresponds to the obvious structure on $\Sigma_g\times S^1$.

This leads to similar forms for the partition functions of the two theories, as shown on page 2 of Thompson. That is, for $\Sigma_g\times S^1$, one finds the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem for a power of the fundamental line bundle on the moduli space of flat connections on $\Sigma_g\times S^1$, while for $M_{g,p}$ one finds a simple generalization.

This brings me to my question. Since instanton Floer homology is defined using the Chern-Simons functional, **is there a simple relationship between the instanton Floer homology of $M_{g,p}$ and $\Sigma_g\times S^1$?**

Comment: As far as I know  the instanton Floer homology is well defined only for $3$-manifolds $M$ with $b_1(M)\leq 1$  and one has to be careful about the symmetry groups $SO(3)$  vs $SU(2)$